# Как склеить 4 unsigned char в один unsigned int

Tags: c++, битовые-операции

Объясните, пожалуйста, как использовать битовый сдвиг для того, чтобы из четырёх переменных `unsigned char` получить одну `unsigned int`, затем проделать обратное действие.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Последовательно в младшую часть int кладем очередной байт и сдвигаем влево на 8 бит. Что бы положить 1 байт в младшую часть используем логическое ИЛИ:

```
unsigned char c1=5,c2=10,c3=98,c4=67;
unsigned int I;
I=c4;  // c4 в младших 8и битах, остальные 0
I<<=8; // Сдвигаем int влево на 8 бит. Младшие 8 бит становятся 0, c4 становится в 9-16 битах.
I|=c3; // Логическое ИЛИ заменяет 0 биты на те, что в байте c3
I<<=8; I|=c2; I<<=8; I|=c1; // Аналогично кладем остальные байты
```

Для обратного действия сдвигаем int так, что бы нужный нам байт был самым младшим и маскируем остальные биты логическим И:

```
c1=I & 0xFF;
c2=(I>>8) & 0xFF;
c3=(I>>16) & 0xFF;
c4=(I>>24) & 0xFF;
```

Только следим за [порядком байт](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2), на разных архитектурах числа в int принято класть по разному.

Comment: А какая разница в каком порядке хранятся байты (`BIG_ENDIAN`/`LITTLE_ENDIAN`)? Это ведь отвечает лишь за порядок, в котором представлены байты в памяти машины, а при работе с `int` это не имеет значения (байты всегда развернутся в одинаковом порядке), мы ведь не накладываем переменную типа `int`, на какую-то область памяти по её адресу. Разве нет?

Comment: Это на всякий случай замечание, я же не знаю что потом с этим int будет дальше происходить. Может его решат в файл записать как готовый int и будут ожидать определенного порядка

Comment: Окей, тогда вопрос снят. Просто прочитав ответ я начал сомневаться в том, что это отвечает лишь на порядок представления байт в памяти машины :)

Comment: @Mike Так ли нужно выполнять операцию `& 0xFF`? Можно просто `(unsigned char)(I>>8)` и т. д. И хотя не глупый компилятор сгенерирует одинаковый код в обоих случаях, я всё же не уверен, что все компиляторы не глупые и поймут, что побитовое И можно не делать.

Comment: @АртёмКараваев Я вот опасаюсь не делать. как компилятор поймет прямое приведение типа из int в char, какой из байтов возьмет на litle и big endian платформах. Хотя с другой стороны догадается ли взять правильный после &... может и не нужно

Answer (score 3):

Если вам нужно делать только такую операцию упаковки/распаковки то могу предложить вообще не используя битовые операции.

```
unsigned int UI = 0x12345678;
char *CC = (char *)(&UI);
for (int i=3;i>=0;i--)
    cout << (int)CC[i]<<" ";
unsigned char NC[4] = {120,86,52,18};
unsigned int TI = *(unsigned int *)(NC);
cout << TI;
```

Идея основана на явном преобразовании указателя.
https://ideone.com/1P4tfc запускаемый пример.

Comment: @Abyx, по крайней мере на на x86 в g++ это работать будет (да и трудно предположить, что найдется реальный компилятор, который  нарушит тут (вот в этом коде) *выравнивание* (с чего бы ему вставлять паддинг в 1, 2 или 3 байта в стеке перед NC[4]?)) А strict aliasing (несмотря на предупреждения стандарта) в данном случае imho перебор.

Answer (score 2):

Например, вот так:

```
int main()
{
    unsigned char ch1 = 0x1;
    unsigned char ch2 = 0x2;
    unsigned char ch3 = 0x3;
    unsigned char ch4 = 0x4;

    unsigned int value = ch1;

    value <<= 8;
    value |= ch2;

    value <<= 8;
    value |= ch3;

    value <<= 8;
    value |= ch4;
}
```

---

Или чуть более общий вариант решения:

```
#include <array>

const size_t BYTE_COUNT_IN_INT  = 4;
const size_t BITS_COUNT_IN_BYTE = 8;

unsigned int getIntFromCharsArray(const std::array<unsigned char, BYTE_COUNT_IN_INT>& charsArray)
{
    unsigned int result = charsArray[0];
    for (size_t i = 1; i <= BYTE_COUNT_IN_INT - 1; ++i)
    {
        result <<= BITS_COUNT_IN_BYTE;
        result |= charsArray[i];
    }
    return result;
}

std::array<unsigned char, BYTE_COUNT_IN_INT> getCharsArrayFromInt(unsigned int value)
{
    std::array<unsigned char, BYTE_COUNT_IN_INT> result;
    for (size_t i = 0; i <= BYTE_COUNT_IN_INT - 1; ++i)
    {
        result[BYTE_COUNT_IN_INT - i - 1] = value;
        value >>= BITS_COUNT_IN_BYTE;
    }
    return result;
}

int main()
{
    const std::array<unsigned char, BYTE_COUNT_IN_INT> charsArray = { 0x1, 0x2, 0x3, 0x4 };
    unsigned int intFromCharsArray = getIntFromCharsArray(charsArray);

    auto charsArrayFromInt = getCharsArrayFromInt(intFromCharsArray);
}
```

Comment: @Abyx не надо писать 'не правильно', это неправильно. :) Про 'void' согласен, наследие MS.

Answer (score 0):

Дополню. Если нужна именно конвертация и можно не использовать битовые сдвиги, то самое простое решение через `union`:

```
union converter
{
    unsigned int number;
    unsigned char bytes[4];
};
```

---

Число в байты:

```
converter c;
c.number = 123;
// c.bytes[0] == 0xD2
// c.bytes[1] == 0x04
// c.bytes[2] == 0x00
// c.bytes[3] == 0x00
```

---

Байты в число:

```
converter c;
c.bytes[0] = 1;
c.bytes[1] = 2;
c.bytes[2] = 3;
c.bytes[3] = 4;
// c.number == 0x04030201 (big-endian)
```

Comment: Нарушение strict aliasing = UB.