# Как побайтно записать uint32 и обратно?

Tags: c

Есть массив с 4 байтами, как их поместит в uint32?

```
uint8 arr[4] = {0xDD, 0xFF, 0xCC, 0xBB};
uint32 ret = ...;
```

И провести обратную операцию:

```
uint32 i = 0xDDFFCCBB;
uint8 arr[4] = ...;
```

Comment: `ret = *(uint32*)arr;` работает?

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/510193 оно?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если бы они у вас оба были с одним порядком байт - не было бы проблем:

```
uint8 arr[4] = {0xDD, 0xFF, 0xCC, 0xBB};
uint32 ret = *(uint32*)arr;
```

В вашем же варианте придется

```
ret = arr[3]|(arr[2] << 8)|(arr[1] << 16)|(arr[0] << 24);
```

Обратно - примерно так же:

```
arr[3] = ret&0xFF;
arr[2] = (ret >> 8)&0xFF;
arr[1] = (ret >> 16)&0xFF;
arr[0] = (ret >> 24)&0xFF;
```

Comment: `Если бы они у вас оба были с одним порядком байт - не было бы проблем` Проблемы есть — это неопределённое поведение, т.к. нарушено strict aliasing rule, и могут быть нарушены требования по выравниванию. `arr[1] << 16` На системах с 16-битным типом `int` данный сдвиг также вызывает неопределённое поведение.

Comment: Честно говоря, уже так достал этот strict aliasing, что, признавая вашу правоту, так и хочется попросить показать хоть один компьютер, где это реально не будет работать...

Comment: `так и хочется попросить показать хоть один компьютер, где это реально не будет работать` Ну, допустим, [вот такой пример](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d75b2cfa53da3a40).

Comment: @wololo Я сказал *ЭТО*, т.е. код из ответа, а не надуманная конструкция типа `alignas(int) alignas(char8_t) char8_t arr[sizeof(int)]`... Откровенно говоря, такое обилие `alignas` вызывает тоску и непонимание, что, а главное, зачем и за чем выравнивается... Кстати, VC++ на тот код отвечает `-1 255`.

Comment: Хотите сказать работоспособность вашего примера гарантируется только, когда кроме ваших двух строчек кода в программе больше ничего нет?) `alignas` нужны, чтобы исключить проблемы с выравниванием, но без них [тоже не работает](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/476520e3ed454891).

Comment: Еще раз и медленно - не придуманный пример, призванный надурить оптимизатор, а код `uint8 arr[4] = {0xDD, 0xFF, 0xCC, 0xBB};
uint32 ret = *(uint32*)arr;`

Comment: Ну, вы так и пишите в ответе, что для работоспособности вашего примера, кроме приведённых двух строчек, в программе ничего не должно быть.  ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ Хотя бы один компьютер, где ЭТО: `*(uint32*)arr` не работает, я привёл.

Comment: Бессмысленная дискуссия. И совершенно бессмысленно поднимать ее через почти 6 лет после ответа на вопрос... Как я уже написал - формально вы правы. Надеюсь, этого достаточно? Или вы хотите, чтобы я исправил свой ответ? Но ведь вы имеете возможность вносить правки сами, за чем дело стало? :)

Answer (score 1):

Есть другой способ - использование объединений. Порядок байт в этом случае не имеет значения. Объединения в C похожи на структуры с той лишь разницей, что каждый элемент объединения расположен по одному и тому же адресу памяти. В вашем случае это будет выглядеть так:

```
typedef union {
    uint32 word,
    uint8 bytes[sizeof(uint32)]
} WordChar;
```

В дальнейшем вы можете использовать тип `WordChar` следующим образом:

```
WordChar wc;
wc.bytes[0] = 0xDD;
wc.bytes[1] = 0xFF;
wc.bytes[2] = 0xCC;
wc.bytes[3] = 0xBB;
uint32 ret = wc.word; //0xDDFFCCBB
```

То же касается типа `float`: разбить его на байты можно таким же способом. [Вот моя статья, где всё подробно описано](http://alouette.su/page/porjadok-bajt).

Comment: Все очень плохо с вашим решением. Оно нарушает strict-aliasing и годится для удивления коллег со словами "глянь, ошибка в компеляторе!!!!11"

Дело в том, что C запрещает писать в одни поля union, а читать из других. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2906365/gcc-strict-aliasing-and-casting-through-a-union

Comment: @gbg, если нельзя писать в одни поля, а читать из других, то зачем тогда вообще вводили union?

Comment: К тому же, если бы речь шла о float, то решение Harry уже не сработало бы. Только объединения.

Comment: @gdb По вашей ссылке Abyx пишет что char и uchar это особый случай. Кто прав?

Comment: `Порядок байт в этом случае не имеет значения.` Не понятно, с чего это вдруг порядок байт перестал иметь значение? Ведь даже в вашем примере на некоторых системах в `ret` [будет записано вовсе не `0xDDFFCCBB`](https://rextester.com/QZL98402).

Answer (score 0):

В свое время мне нравилось вот такое решение:

```
uint32_t val32 = 0xAABBCCDD;
uint8_t arr[4];
uint8_t arr[0] = ((uint8_t*)&val32)[0];
uint8_t arr[1] = ((uint8_t*)&val32)[1];
uint8_t arr[2] = ((uint8_t*)&val32)[2];
uint8_t arr[3] = ((uint8_t*)&val32)[3];
```

В результате имеем:
`arr[0] = 0xDD, arr[1] = 0xCC, arr[2] = 0xBB, arr[3] = 0xAA`

Comment: Для некоторых платформ даст неверный результат. Пометка для x86/x64 обязательна. Именно поэтому люди пишут более сложные решения.

Comment: Более того, внутренний параноик подсказывает, что рано или поздно разработчики стандартной библиотеки додумаются в целях повышения быстродействия сделать тип `uint8_t` псевдонимом не типа `unsigned char`, а некоего иного встроенного `__UINT_8_T__`, и мы автоматически получим неопределённое поведение из-за нарушения strict aliasing rule.